# I cant pass clicked value into function

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

[DEMO Static Value](http://jsfiddle.net/7qL5z4Lx/) :

Hi,
Iam not able to Pass the Clicked Value in to Return Function.

```
function getArtistId() {
            //return 'l-gQLqv9f4o';   if i uncomment this videos will work like charm, but instead of static i need dynamic onclick of the element getting the value and passing.
        return 'ytData1';
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var cVid, ytData1

$('.new li #c-vid').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).each(function(i, obj) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cVid = document.getElementById('c-vid');
        ytData1 = $(this).attr('data-yt');
        console.log(ytData1)
        console.log("ready!");
        
        

        loadPlayer();
        
        
        
    })
});
            
});

function getArtistId() {
    return 'l-gQLqv9f4o';
    
    //return 'ytData1';
}           


function loadPlayer() {
if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        onYouTubePlayer();
    };
}
}

var player;

function onYouTubePlayer() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '490',
    width: '880',
    videoId: getArtistId(),
    playerVars: {
        controls: 1,
        showinfo: 0,
        rel: 0,
        showsearch: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3
    },
    events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': catchError
    }
});
}

var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    // setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
    done = true;
} else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    location.reload();
}
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

//if(typeof(SONG.getArtistId()) == undefined)
//{
//  console.log("undefineeeed"); 
//} 
//event.target.playVideo();   
}

function catchError(event) {
    if (event.data == 100) console.log("De video bestaat niet meer");
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
```

As i have sail not able to Pass the Clicked Value in to Return Function.

it is difficult to find problem in this code for me please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use a global variable, by using `window.variable`

```
$('.new li #c-vid').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).each(function(i, obj) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cVid = document.getElementById('c-vid');
        window.artist_id = $(this).attr('data-yt');

        loadPlayer();
    })
});
```

and then just update your `getArtistId` function

```
function getArtistId() {
  return window.artist_id;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind to select my answer as the right answer for your question? Thx

Comment: You gave me a vote but didn't selected it as the right answer, if you check under the vote there is a small green mark which you can press and that will mark my answer as the right answer. Thx